# How do I count how many of these columns have a value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assume the following table:

```
ID | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | Item5
------------------------------------------
A  | NULL  | NULL  | YES   | YES   | NULL
B  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | YES   | NULL
C  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | NULL
```

I want to return the following data set:

```
ID  | Count
------------
A   | 2
B   | 1
C   | 0
```

Basically, I want a count how many of the columns of Item1-5 are NOT `NULL` for that ID

How can I do this in MS-SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not tested, but something like this should work.

```
SELECT
  Id,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN Item1 is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    +
    CASE WHEN Item2 is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    +
    CASE WHEN Item3 is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    +
    CASE WHEN Item4 is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    +
    CASE WHEN Item5 is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    ) 'Count'
FROM 
   tableName
GROUP BY 
   Id
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'll BET that ID is a primary key, which means that the `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` are not needed and will just add overhead to the query

Comment: I thought the same thing, but didn't want to assume.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (ID char(1), Item1 varchar(3), Item2 varchar(3), Item3 varchar(3), Item4 varchar(3), Item5 varchar(3))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('A'  , NULL  , NULL  , 'YES' , 'YES' , NULL)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('B'  , NULL  , NULL  , NULL  , 'YES' , NULL)
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('C'  , NULL  , NULL  , NULL  , NULL  , NULL)

SELECT
    ID, CASE WHEN ITEM1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       +CASE WHEN ITEM2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       +CASE WHEN ITEM3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       +CASE WHEN ITEM4 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       +CASE WHEN ITEM5 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [Count]
    FROM @YourTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID   Count
---- -----------
A    2
B    1
C    0

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT ID, (case when item1 is null then 0 else 1 end)+
           (case when item2 is null then 0 else 1 end)+
           (case when item3 is null then 0 else 1 end)+
           (case when item4 is null then 0 else 1 end)+
           (case when item5 is null then 0 else 1 end) AS Count 
FROM Table
ORDER BY ID
```

I hope this is a hypothetical question and not an actual production table.

Comment: It's actually a really weird one-time sales query wanting to know if a product has certain properties not set to null

Comment: Thanks Joe for adding the ends :) .

Comment: you will get an error with this code, because  "END" is required for each CASE.  Also, the "when NULL" will not work and each row will return a count of 5.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli, you fixed the "ends" but **this query STILL returns the wrong results.**  Use the  sample code from my answer and plug this query in and try it yourself.  the CASE is ill formed, should be `CASE WHEN item1 IS NULL then...` like in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option: If you're in sql 2k5 or later you can also use an unpivot to count all non-null values. You won't get any rows for zero-counts directly from this query though. It does however save the tedium of case statements.

```
select
    ID, count(ItemCount) as ItemCount
from
(
    select ID, Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5
    from TableA a
) t
unpivot
(
    ItemCount for Item in
    (
        Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5
    )
) as unpvt
group by
    ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Another technique.

```
SELECT
    ID, 
    (SELECT COUNT(C) FROM( 
            SELECT Item1 C 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT Item2 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT Item3 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT Item4 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT Item5)
             D)
AS [Count]
FROM @YourTable
```