# Select records where more than one field has data in the same record - a customer can order one or more books

Tags: sql, excel, vba

[Example of the Database Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRgID.jpg)
[fields on table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXD0x.jpg)
I'm trying running a SQL query from an Excel spread sheet that is used for printing packing slips and labels.

The query runs on a table where each row has a unique customer.
Each row also has multiple columns with a date if a book was ordered by a customer.
I need to pull only the rows where a customer has ordered more than one book regardless of the date ordered.

If a row only has one book column with a order date I want to skip that row.
If a row has more then one book column with an order date I want to pull that row to my spread sheet.

Answer (score 0):

What is the formatting of your table? Is this one line per order, one line per customer? Showing us a sample of data in the table, and the data you'd like to get would go a long way here.

Comment: I added a picture of what the data base records/fields look like labeled "Example of the Database Fields

Comment: that looks like you're trying to find how many columns have values then... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945890/how-do-i-count-how-many-of-these-columns-have-a-value-in-sql should be exactly what you're looking for.